# So Why Didn't I get my Populist Badge?

Tags: support, badges, votes

I've read up on the requirements for this badge, and a recent answer of mine appears to fit the bill

[How can you possibly stop/kill a person who has the ability to stop time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55953/how-can-you-possibly-stop-kill-a-person-who-has-the-ability-to-stop-time/55955#55955)

My answer is the top scored one (71 votes as of this writing), but the accepted answer only has 21 votes.

So, my answer has more than double the votes of the accepted answer (more than 3x).

I do see in my answer history that my post *was* marked as accepted and then was retracted soon afterwards - would this affect the metrics for this badge?

Or do I have to wait for the end of the day?

Comment: They process at certain times of day, I think it's around every 4 hours.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Hah.  The SE Gods were looking down on me, the badge literally just popped up.

Comment: Yeah, some badges are only checked once a day, some once every few hours, some every 5-10 minutes.  I think it depends on both frequency and computational expense; for a rare badge I guess they figure you can wait a few hours. :-)

Comment: Hail Glarnak!!!

Answer (score 1):

As has been discussed in the comments, awarding of badges doesn't happen in real time.

If a badge hasn't been awarded after 24-36 hours, then raise the issue; if it hasn't yet been that long, just be patient and it should be awarded.